# c# URL Rewrite - Same pattern with different page targets

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

How to rewrite in asp.net webforms same pattern urls to different pages, mapping from database?
I have the following URLs:

www.site.com/categoryname (redirect to category.aspx?name=categoryname
www.site.com/categoryname/2 (redirect to category.aspx?name=categoryname&page=2
www.site.com/categoryname/filtername (redirect to category.aspx?name=categoryname&filter=filtername)
www.site.com/categoryname/productname (redirect to product.aspx?name=productname)
www.site.com/brandname (redirect to brand.aspx?name=brandname)

So, the pattern of brand/category single pages are the same, also the pattern for category/product and category/filter are the same. In IIS rewrite I can't do this, because I can't "predict" what is the right page. There is any way to lookup at a database table to redirect to the right page and handle specific cases that I dont need to lookup the database (like example with pagination, just the first part will be in database and I need to know that the user is in page 2)

Thanks!

Comment: I usually have to put some hardcoded strings to make a distinction between pages like '/brand/brandname/categoryname' and '/category/categoryname/product' where brand and category are hardcoded strings

Comment: Thanks for your comment Pedro. We already use a structure like this, but our SEO consulting asked to reduce the "/" and remove this initial steps, going to categories to first string after the domain name.